# How to include .cshtml inside html page?

Tags: html, razor

I want to load a .cshtml page inside html page (I dont want to redirect to another page).I tried using 
           `$("#containerdiv").load("folder/Default.cshtml")` or `$("#containerdiv").load("folder")` (html pages load successfully with this method) but when I saw the source code only heading was loaded into **containerdiv**. Is there other way to do this ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? .cshtml is a server file and the browser is going to have no idea how to parse any of the special syntax.

Comment: @Antiga I am a newbie in SQL database management. I have learnt to do it in razor c# only so I want to load that page inside my html page which contain other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an `iframe`. With an `iframe` you can show the page within the page and view it's code from the same page. Try this

```
    <iframe src="folder/Default.cshtml"></iframe>
```

Of course, this is only if your not going to anything with server code, which i'm guessing is what you want to do. You can't load server code from an html page because the browser processes the page, not the server.

EDIT:
Try this instead:

```
    <iframe src="FULL_PATH_TO_FOLDER_HERE/folder/Default.cshtml"></iframe>
```

EDIT 2:
Since that's alot to type everytime, you could also do this, see if it works:

```
    <iframe src="./folder/Default.cshtml"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this also failed when I viewed the source code I saw some errors.

Comment: it loads a page showing 'Server Error in '/' Application.  The resource cannot be found.'

Comment: try editing your permissions. What server software are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Webmatrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can't load the cshtml directly, you need to call your controller which should return a partial view of the cshtml file

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with controller right now. I am newbie and just know razor c# syntax to process variables.

Comment: Cshtml file is not pure html, it can not be rendered directly by browser, it should be first processed by the server to produce the pure html to be understood by browser, loading cshtml file from script as you did will not work

Comment: Please provide more detail about your server(cshtml,controller) to further help you